# How to perform object level validation in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

*serializer.py*:

```
class ExamTermSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField()
    end_date = serializers.DateField()
    course = serializers.IntegerField()
    _class = serializers.IntegerField()

def validate(self,data):
    if data['start_date'] > data['end_date']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Start Date Should be smaller") 
    return data
```

*views.py*:

```
 ###Bunch of code..
       _exm,c = ExamTerm.objects.get_or_create(name = data['name'],
                                                    defaults = {
                                                        'start_date':data['start_date'],
                                                        'end_date':data['end_date'],
                                                        'course_id':data['course'],
                                                        '_class_id':data['_class']
                                                    })
                if not c:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError({
                    "Detail":['Exam With This name Already Exist']
                                                })
                return Response(data , status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

When I search about object level validation in DRF I found that this validate function that I have written in serializer (i.e `validate`).

My actual problem in how to implement this `validate` function from views so that the `start_date` will be always smaller than `end_date`.

Comment: you are question is not clear enough. Can you please edit with more details and complete function of your api-end point code.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue where when saving an object, the `validate` function is just not called.

Answer (score -2):

You need to override `save()` method of your `ExamTerm` model

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if not self.start_date > self.end_date:
        super(ExamTerm,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    else:
        raise ValidationError('start date can not be greater than end date')
```